# VSCode Intellisense and powershell terminal reacts strongly delayed

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I'm using VSCode (1.41.1) on a Windows Server 2016 (10.0.14393.0) RDP Session with the PowerShell Extension (2020.1.0) installed. PowerShell Version: 5.1.14393.3053.

Since more than 6 month (and several VSCode and PowerShell Extension versions) the Intellisense is very slow (takes nearly one minute) - while intellisense is not reacting, the powershell console also does not accept input.

I don't know the trigger, but this happens every few minutes. In between, it works as desired.
When there is no response there is a circled arrow and the word PowerShell on the left bottom of VSCode (see picture). As soon, as the reaction is back, this sign disappears.

Any ideas or hints, how I can find out, what Intellisense is waiting for?

[image: [Image of the appering arrow circle and PowerShell in VSCode]

Comment: Did some research recently. Found "
IntelliSense is occasionally slow when editing PowerShell scripts"
 on [vscode-powershell issue #647](https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/647) and [vscode-powershell issue #647](https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/1256) - but still no solution till now.

Comment: Should get better with the new powershell extension for VSCode. See https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/releases/tag/v2020.3.0 - waiting for closing till I have more experience with the extension.